# What is the difference between しました and した

Tags: grammar, verbs

> 週末に何をしましたか。

Here what is the grammer of `しましたか`.

Shouldn't it simply be `したか`, where `した` is the `た` format of `する` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is (quote Jisho.org) the past **polite** conjugation of the verb `する`.

> 週末に何をしましたか。
>
> What did you do this weekend? (polite)

Your intention of using `した` is correct, however it is the **casual** (for a lack of better word) conjugation of `する`. You would end up with a sentence like this:

> 週末に何をしたか。

However, this is still kind of awkward as when speaking in a casual manner, you would tend to drop the `か` question particle and just say the sentence with a rising intonation. Your question would then end up like this:

> 週末に何をした？
>
> What did you do this weekend (casual)
>
> 週末、何をした？ (even more casual)

Hope this helped!

Comment: Very useful answer.